# How do I can coffee with milk? Basically a canned latte

Tags: storage-lifetime, coffee, milk, canning

I've been running my coffee shop for a while now and would like to venture into the world of canning my specialty drinks. my biggest hiccup so far is how to preserve the milk. I've seen that most canned coffees with milk use nonfat milk with either pectin or xanthan gum to make up for the lack of milk texture, but nothing on how they preserve the milk. ive done quite a lot of digging but can't find what these companies use to stabilize their milk products. Please let me know if you have any insight into how I can start this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can do this on your own. Home-canning safety regulations explicitly forbid any canning of dairy. That would cover also any sale under cottage-industry licences.

If you want to do this as a part of your business, it might be possible to find an industrial canner who would handle the canning for you. At that point, you're no longer responsible for coming up with the procedure, it will be the canner's food technologists who will take care of it.

How you find that canner, or how feasible it is practically, legally or financially, is out of scope for our site.

Comment: sweet thank you. we would definitely be going through a canner for this project, I just trying to learn as much as I can beforehand.

Comment: Then I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If you want to have an idea at what could happen at the canner, here is a random video of a production line for canning coffee, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkSGw4m9enE. They appear to brew it on-site, but I'm sure that a canner who takes outside orders will have worked out logistical solutions.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing to keep in mind is to avoid the typical mistakes that can spoil our coffee, and follow the basic rules so that our drink is top class: use original beans, as fresh as possible, freshly roasted, and freshly ground. , with a clean coffee maker and also using quality water.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question?